Define form validator for form without data class in Symfony
I have defined a Form without data class, and I want to attach validator for full data (NOT for separate fields). I.e:
class SkillLikeType extends AbstractType {
  ...
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void {
    $builder
      ->add('skills', ChoiceType::class, ...)
      ->add('liker_id', HiddenType::class);
  }

  public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void {
    $constraints[] = new DuplicateSkillLikes(); <-- I need full data validation here
    $resolver->setDefaults([
      'data_class' => null,
      'constraints' => $constraints
    ]);
  }
}

Symfony example talks only about per-field validation, which does not suit me. If I add class or property-level validators here, I always get empty array as validator input, like this:
class SkillLikeType extends AbstractType {
  ...
  public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void {
    $constraints[] = new DuplicateSkillLikes; // prevent liking multiple times
    ...
  }
}

class DuplicateSkillLikes extends Constraint {
  public function getTargets(): string {
    return self::PROPERTY_CONSTRAINT; // no matter what I put here
  }
}

class DuplicateSkillLikesValidator extends ConstraintValidator {
  ...
  public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint) {
    // here value is always empty array
  }
}

For entity-based forms, constraints defined in configureOptions can be piled up and they are executed in their defined order but array forms treat those as per-field validators, it seems. Any ideas? Can I even attach validator in Form class or do I need to call it separately in controller?
Symfony version is 6.1.
EDIT:
Tried to pass constraint object instead of array of constraint objects in configureOptions but same result.

Have you tried $constraints['skills' => new DuplicateSkillsLikes()];?

Found the problem, not related to Validators or Forms. I had set mapped=false for all form fields...
    $builder
      ->add('skills', ChoiceType::class, ['mapped' => false]);

